# Determinant of Jacobian equivalent to absolute of derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

In [this report](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abdulfatir/normalizing-flows/master/report/report.pdf), Equation 10 it is claimed that we can make the jump from

$$
p(y) = p(f^{-1}(y)) \cdot \left| \frac{d f^{-1}}{dy} \right|
$$

to:
$$
p(\mathbf{y}) = p(f^{-1}(\mathbf{y})) \cdot \left| \text{det} \frac{d f^{-1}}{d\mathbf{y}} \right|
$$

where we can replace the derivative with the determinant of the Jacobian in the multivariate case. Can someone explain this jump? What is this called? What's the proof?

Comment: [Change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Application_in_probability)